# How to display HTML in WebView in Windows 8 Metro app?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm building an app for Win8 (Metro) and for WP8. In this app I have a WebView in which I need to load some webpage. 
I'm getting HTML via post request in WP8 like this:

```
void LoadView(string username, string password)
        {
            string postDataStr = String.Format("username={0}&password={1}", 
                username, password);
            byte[] postDataByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postDataStr);

            string additionalHeaders = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" + Environment.NewLine;

            var urlLogin = new Uri(new Uri(APIConf.API_SERVICE_ENDPOINT), APIConf.LOGIN_URL);
            myWebView.Navigate(urlLogin, postDataByte, additionalHeaders);
        }
```

That works just fine, but I am having problems with Win8 Metro app. I have tried like this:

```
    async Task<string> GetWebContent(string username, string password)
            {
                string serviceMethod = APIConf.LOGIN_URL;

                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(APIConf.API_SERVICE_ENDPOINT);

                HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)
                });

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(serviceMethod, content);
                Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

                String sResponse = null;
                using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    sResponse = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                return sResponse;
            }

async void LoadViewInWin8(string username, string password)
        {
            var htmlContent = await API.APIController.GetWebContent(username, password);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlContent))
            {
                myWebView.NavigateToString(htmlContent);
            }
        }
```

When I execute this code, myWebView load and show HTML that I got, but it doesn't load any of the styles from web. Also, when I click on some of the links in shown html, I get page "Navigation to the webpage was canceled".
I know that Win8 WebView has some problem with Navigate() methoid but is there a way that I can load this webPage in my WebView properly? I really would appreciate any help that I can get with this.

Comment: Are styles urls absolute or relative? What about links?

Comment: That explains it. They need to be absolute.

Comment: @Denis, you have actually answered my question :).
My html is as it should be, and thank you for that.
Now, problem is that I am not logged in even if my request did log me in, so when I navigate to some link in my HTML it redirect me to login webpage.

Comment: You might have to intercept navigation to url and repeat same process you do in LoadView. Now, I know it is possible to intercept navigation in WP8 WebBrowser control, but I don't know if Win8 WebView allows it.